# Speech Synthesizer not working giving an error

Tags: text-to-speech

I get an exception running this simple program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace speechSynth1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            s.Speak("Hello how are you");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the exceptions.

```
Unhandled Exception : System.PlatformNotSupportedExecption : No voice installed on
 the system or none available with the current security setting.
   at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.Sythesis.VoiceSythesis..ctor<WeakReference speechSynthesizer>
   at Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.get_VoiceSynthesizer()
   at Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(Prompt prompt)
   at Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(String textToSpeak)
   at speechSynth1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\project\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\speechSynth1\speechSynth1\Program.cs : line 14
```

I don't understand what is wrong. I have just checked the control panel and the voice is correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.Speech instead of Microsoft.Speech